# Using function from module in JavaScript script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use an exported constant from a JS module. My simple script is like

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const pi = require('./custom_math').pi
console.log(pi)
```

But the module I require has an import, so It raises the following error:

```
$ ./script.js
<path_to_module>/index.js:1
import anotherconstant from '<other_module>'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (./script.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

How can I make a script that uses the `pi` constant from the `simple_math/index.js` file?

Comment: What version of node are you running this in?

Comment: ...well, the error's message kinda tells - use should create a Module (for example, you file should have `module.export = ... ` in the end) to use `import / require ` in node.js ... (and ,btw, if you would want to use 'import ...' clauses in you node.js javascript (ie. no transpilation to commonjs), you should ('type: module' in package.json)  have : https://github.com/VovanSuper/MERN-dummy/blob/main/server/package.json#L25

Comment: I'm using node version v16.11.0

Comment: @Vovan_Super But I want to create a script, not a module. It would be possible to "run" that module?

Comment: you have to tell node that you are using modules. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-an-es6-import-in-node-js/

Comment: @DavidDavó, why not ..? (run it normally: `node file.js` ... ( in the same repo: https://github.com/VovanSuper/MERN-dummy/blob/main/server/package.json#L27 ) )  ... which runs the file: https://github.com/VovanSuper/MERN-dummy/blob/main/server/index.js

Comment: Is there any way of doing it without modifying the module code (`./custom_math`) or the `package.json` file?

Comment: can't you replace `import` statement with `require` ? `const anotherconstant = require('<other_module>')`